# How to a clone remote repository in Thermal?

Tags: git, git-gui

I tried cloning a remote repository in [Thermal application](https://thermal.codecarrot.net), but it didn't work.

[Clone repository pop-up modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLtlK.png)

After adding all the detail like:

- Name
- Remote URL
- Path

After clicking the clone button, it should start cloning, but it doesn't clone the repository and the progress bar is stuck at zero.

Comment: Were you trying to clone a public or private repository?

Comment: Public repository.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Also, did you got any error in the console? _(you can open devtools by pressing `ctrl+shift+i`)_

Comment: Using w10, not sure about console message, let me check those.

Comment: Which Thermal version are you using?

Comment: I don't see any error message related to cloning except for moment.js warning message.

Comment: I am using Thermal version v0.0.4

Comment: Okay, thank you for answering all the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the **core developer of [Thermal Git application](https://github.com/gitthermal/thermal)**, as you have answered the questions in the above comments, according to that I understood that there is no issue with cloning the repository.

The cloning feature should work as expected, it's just that the progress bar doesn't work in the current release *(I am working on that issue, to fix it)*.

Now, the time taken by Thermal to clone the repository **depends upon the size of the remote repository** you are trying to clone. **Open the location you have selected to clone the repository**, you should see the repository cloned over there.

If you still don't see the repository folder, try changing the folder name you type in clone repository modal.

[image]

---

If that doesn't work either, then there could be two possible reasons the cloning didn't work:

1. You are trying to clone a big repository which is still cloning and might take more time.
2. Your machine security system might be blocking access to download the files.

Thank you for posting the question, I suggest you post your future questions related to Thermal in [Thermal Discord Server](https://discord.gg/DcSNmts).

Plz, don't forget to give an upvote.